# Detect if webapp is in landscape orientation and add padding-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

What I want the script:

-detect if site is in standalone app
-detect if site is in landscape
-add padding-top to header

```
if (window.navigator.standalone == true && window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){
   $('header').css('padding-top','20px');
}
```

Comment: Try using media queries e.g. `@media screen and (orientation : landscape){ header{ padding-top:20px; } }`.

Comment: i used it already for the webpage but I need a code for the webapp.

Comment: There's nothing a web page can do layout-wise that won't also work in the web app.

Answer (score 2):

Use [media queries](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/) for device-conditional layout:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    header {
        padding-top:20px;
    }
}
```

If the standalone property is really important, detect it in Javascript and add a class to the body:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone == true)
    $('body').addClass('standalone');
```

Then use it in your CSS to apply extra requirements:

```
.standalone header {
    padding-top:20px; /* only applied if standalone */
}
```

You can of course combine the media query with this.

Comment: i don't need a media query, i need a JS/jQuery to change the site.

Comment: @BVSK the media query makes half your code obsolete by embedding it declaratively in CSS, which is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
if (window.navigator.standalone){
 $(window).resize( function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width>height) {
      // Landscape
      $('header').css('padding-top','20px');
      }
    else{
      $('header').css('padding-top','0px');
    }
   });
```

}